# Why is this child div not contained in the parent div's blue background?

Tags: css

Here is the code:

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.t0 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00f; 
}

.t0 .s1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="t0">
    <div class="s1">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbaaaaaabbba</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the `div.s1` contained in `div.t0`'s blue background.

I found the fact that `div.s1` and `div.t0` both are 300px in width very confusing.

I'm looking for the related specs about how width is determined in [css spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/#minitoc), but failed.

Questions:

1. How can one make `div.s1` contained in `div.t0`'s blue background
2. Where are the related specs of this behavior?

Update:
Thank you for the prompt answers! I want to add that I do not want to wrap the long text. I'm confused why are `div.s1` and `div.t0` 300px in width instead of something like 500+px

Comment: do you mean div.s1? I can't find a div class `s0`

Comment: Where is your `div.s0` in CSS?

Comment: @SyamPillai yes, fixed

Comment: And your `div.s1` is inside 'div.t0` only in the example you given. since `div.s1` has no background, it's inside blue only

Comment: Your code works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hb89gfw5/) (for question 1)

Comment: @MarkPerera I tried the JsFiddle, but the width is still 300px

Comment: Width of block elements is by default `width: auto` which is the same as `width: 100%` without padding, border, etc. So the width will be 100% of the parent div (300px). The word being longer than 300px doesn't make the div itself longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the whole word's background to be blue,
Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hb89gfw5/3/)
(added `display: inline-block;` to `t0`)
**Note: This makes your divs inline (you will have to add line breaks <br /> after them to make them position like before)**

Comment: It seems that making `s1` inline-block does not work.

Comment: sorry. Had tested width `width: `x`px` when trying. Will remove it

Answer (score 1):

it is contained, just a browser can not move the text to another place because you have a text from one word.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.t0 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00f; 
}

.t0 .s1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="t0">
    <div class="s1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. Hope you are looking for this solution

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f00;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.t0 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00f; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.t0 .s1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  background: green;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="t0">
    <div class="s1">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbaaaaaabbba</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but word-break: break-all;

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
Wrapper Class contains Red BG
  <div class="t0">
        Your t0 Div Contains Black BG
    <div class="s1">Your S1 Div</div>
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
 // overflow: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.t0 {
  height: 100px;
  border: thin black solid; 
  background-color: #000000; 
  color: #fff;

}

.t0 .s1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;

  border: thin red solid;
}

</style>
```

Try this. If it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

what i understand from you question is the text in div of class s1 is flowing out side to avoid this you can use below css and this can solve issue.

```
.t0 .s1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```